# ASP.Net-MVC sample code to retrieve selected item from html dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can somebody give me an sample code to retreive the item from html.dropdownlist?

Comment: You need to make your question clearer.

Comment: See this question, does it answer yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-value-not-set-via-viewdata-model

Comment: when you asking question, please at least try to be more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have this DropDown in the view:

```
<p><label for="ProductType">Product Type:</label>
<br /><%=Html.DropDownList("ProductTypeDropDown", 
             New SelectList(ViewData("ProductTypes"), 
             "ProductTypeID", "Name"))%>
</p>
```

You can simple retrieve the selected value in the controller using

```
Product.ProductType = form("ProductTypeDropDown")
```

Comment: I am really sorry for not being clear. Anyways, i want the code to retrieve at the controller side.

Comment: umm...I've posted the view and the control side just in case. Did you solved the problem or do you need further assistance?