# How to pass data to the view in mvc asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

let me ask the question first.

Where is the correct place to call a function that load a list of values to be display on a view?

I create a controller like this

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    SeaModel newSea = new SeaModel();

    return View("Season/CreateSea", newSea);
}

//I not quite sure if this should go here or in another place
partial class seaDataContext
{
    public List<string> getSeaSettings()
    {
        var seaSettings = from p in settings
                          where p.setting == "periods"
                          select p.value;

        return seaSettings.ToList<string>();                              
    }
}
```

The model is like

```
public class SeaModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="*")]
    [Display(Name = "Period Name")]
    public string periods { get; set; }    
}
```

Which create a view like

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the following errors.")

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.periods)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Select(model => model.periods, ****My doubt comes here****)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.periods)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    }
```

so, How and where do I pass the return of getSeaSettings() to the view?

Thanks

Comment: sea.. periods... Red Sea for sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

best practice is to make a Selectlist in your Model for this dropdown.

however you also can use the more easy option: using `ViewData`

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     SeaModel newSea = new SeaModel();

     ViewData["myDropDown"] = new SelectList(listOfObjects, "valueOfTheObjectLikeID", "NameYouWantToShowInDropdown");

     return View("Season/CreateSea", newSea);
 }
```

then:

```
@Html.Select(model => model.periods, ViewData["myDropDown"] as SelectList)
```

dont forget in your [HttpPost] method to also fill in the viewdata if you'r validation fails, so the dropdown can be rebuilt.

Comment: This gives me the following errorCompiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Select' takes 2 arguments

Source Error:

                
Line 53: @Html.Select(model => model.periods,ViewData["sl"] as SelectList)

Comment: use SelectFor? i'm dont know much about MVC3 :) also you can input a string which would show by default like "Select your period..."

Comment: in MVC2 that looks like this: <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.someID, ViewData["someList"] as SelectList,"Select a thing...")%>

Comment: MVC3 also has `Html.DropDownListFor()`

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at repository pattern. Have a look at this tutorial at asp.net site
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs

Comment: I agree with using the repository pattern. It's how I've done such things in the past and keeps things nicely separated.

Comment: you may skip (if you opt) interfaces and may create concrete repository classes directly

Answer (score 2):

**Stefanvds**'s approach was what I used to do.
But I found out there is a better way using **`additionalViewData`**.

Use this EditorFor HTML Helper extension method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462.aspx

Instead of passing Select List Items into **ViewData** in the **Controller**, you do this in your **View**.
Pass in your list items as an anonymous object for the `additionalViewData` parameter.
Important thing is to use the **same name** as your Property Name.

```
@Html.EditorFor(
    m => m.MyPropertyName,
    new { MyPropertyName = Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName }
);
```

Of course, you are passing in a View Model object.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int MyPropertyName;

    public IList<SelectListItem> ListItemsForMyPropertyName;
}
```

**`EditorFor` method uses your existing Editor View Templates**.
So you don't need to specify CSS class names and HTML attributes again like when you use the Html.DropDown( ) method.

For example,

```
//------------------------------
// additionalViewData
//------------------------------
@Html.EditorFor(
    m => m.MyPropertyName,
    new { MyPropertyName = Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName }
)

//------------------------------
//  traditional approach requires to pass your own HTML attributes
//------------------------------
@Html.DropDown(
    "MyPropertyName",
    Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName,
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "class", "myDropDownCssClass" }
    }
);

//------------------------------
//  DropDownListFor still requires you to pass in your own HTML attributes
//------------------------------
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.MyPropertyName,
    Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName,
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "class", "myDropDownCssClass" }
    }
);
```

That is why I like the `additionalViewData` approach more.
Because, the HTML code rendered relies on the Editor Templates completely.

Also, using specialized View Models make your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

Hope it helps.