# Populating Dropdowns in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I need to populate a dropdown in ASP.NET MVC 3. I was hoping to get the answers to the following questions:

1. What options do I have. I mean what's the difference between @Html.DropDownList and @Html.DropDownListFor. Also are there any other options?
2. I have the following classes/code. What would be the razor code/HTML syntax I need (I have included what I was trying) in my .cshtml assuming I need to only show this dropdown using the classes below.

   ```
   public class SearchCriterion
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Text { get; set; }

     public string Value { get; set; }
   }

   public class SearchCriteriaViewModel
   {
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SearchCriteria { get; set; }
   }

   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           IList<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem> searchCriteriaSelectList = 
   new List<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>();

           SearchCriteriaViewModel model = new SearchCriteriaViewModel();

           //Some code to populate searchCriteriaSelectList goes here....

           model.SearchCriteria = searchCriteriaSelectList;

           return View(model);
       }
   }

   //Code for Index.cshtml

   @model SearchCriteriaViewModel

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   }

   <p>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchCriteria, 
              new SelectList(SearchCriteria, "Value", "Text"))
     </p>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right side of the lambda `=>` has to be a simple type not the complex type modify your code like

```
public class SearchCriteriaViewModel
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SearchCriterion> SearchCriteria { get; set; }
}

public class SearchCriterion
{     
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

the controller will look like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //fill the select list 
    IEnumerable<SearchCriteria> searchCriteriaSelectList = 
             Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(x=>new SearchCriteria{                 
                Text= x.ToString(),
                Value=ToString(),
            });
    SearchCriteriaViewModel model = new SearchCriteriaViewModel();
    //Some code to populate searchCriteriaSelectList goes here....
    model.SearchCriteria = searchCriteriaSelectList;
    return View(model);
}
```

in the view

```
@model SearchCriteriaViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

   <p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, 
           new SelectList(model.SearchCriteria , "Value", "Text"))
  </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works with minor modifications. However, i wasn't able to understand the DropDownListFor syntax. What does the model => model.Id part represent. We don't populate the Id anywhere.

Comment: it `returns an HTML select element for each property in the object that is represented by the specified expression` here are more details about it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor.aspx

Answer (score 2):

After extensively using ASP.NET MVC for the past 3 years, I prefer using **`additionalViewData`** from the [`Html.EditorFor()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff406462.aspx) more.

Pass in your **[List Items]** as an `anonymous` object with the **same property name** as the Model's property into the `Html.EditorFor()` method.

The benefit is that `Html.EditorFor()` method automatically uses your *Editor Templates*.
So you don't need to provide CSS class names for your Drop Down Lists.
See comparison below.

```
//------------------------------
// additionalViewData                <=== RECOMMENDED APPROACH
//------------------------------
@Html.EditorFor(
    m => m.MyPropertyName,
    new { MyPropertyName = Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName }
)

//------------------------------
//  traditional approach requires to pass your own HTML attributes
//------------------------------
@Html.DropDown(
    "MyPropertyName",
    Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName,
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "class", "myDropDownCssClass" }
    }
);

//------------------------------
//  DropDownListFor still requires you to pass in your own HTML attributes
//------------------------------
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.MyPropertyName,
    Model.ListItemsForMyPropertyName,
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "class", "myDropDownCssClass" }
    }
);
```

If you want more details, please refer to [my answer in another thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087815/how-to-pass-data-to-the-view-in-mvc-asp-net/4099487#4099487).