# set both Default value and CSS Class of Html.DropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have in my controller:

```
   ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(new CityRepository().GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.Name),"CityId", "Name", new Guid("74898AD1-73BB-41E1-B1E1-484EACAFA4C4"));
```

And in My View:

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("CityId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CityId, new { @class = "select-choice-1" })%>
```

But the problem is that default value wasn't selected.How can I set default value and Css Class at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different constructor for the drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCity, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CityId, "Select a City", new { @class = "select-choice-1" })
```

Further reading: [MVC 3 Layout Page, Razor Template, and DropdownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674033/mvc-3-layout-page-razor-template-and-dropdownlist)

Comment: If you look at my controller code , I want to set dropdowlist selected value to value "74898AD1-73BB-41E1-B1E1-484EACAFA4C4" ,not to "Please select a city...."

Comment: You need to review the controller constructor I posted. "Select a City" is simply the option label. IT IS NOT, the selected value. This is not a unique problem you are having, here is another example on what to do to fix your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-value-not-set-via-viewdata-model